# Align cells of MAtrixPlot with DendrogramPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix

I would like to plot the MatrixPlot and DendrogramPlot in such way that row and columns of the matrix would be alined with branches of DendrogramPlot, but the best I could to plot is shown below:

[image]

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"];
RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
Grid@{{DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate[%], ImageSize -> 500], ""}, 
   {MatrixPlot[%, ImageSize -> 500], 
  Rotate[DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate[%], ImageSize -> 500], -Pi/2]}}
```

I need to get something like this:

[image]

Any ideas how I can get such result?

Comment: Do you want to find an automatic way to align them, or are you satisfied with manually changing the image size of dendrograms: ``Grid@{{DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate[%], ImageSize -> 425], ""}, {MatrixPlot[%, ImageSize -> 500], Rotate[DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate[%], ImageSize -> 425], -Pi/2]}}`` ?

Comment: of course I would like to do it automatically